# Bathroom exhaust vent

Tags: bathroom, exhaust

After my modular house was delivered i had the house sided. For some reason the siding guys went right over my bathroom exhaust exit. I have an idea where it is and the plans show it’s 36 inches off the bathroom window. It just doesn’t show the exact height and I don’t want to just start cutting into my brand new siding. What is a good way to find out exactly where it is?

Comment: Do you have an accessible attic over the bathroom?

Comment: A modular home's location drawings might actually be accurate. How difficult would it be to remove some siding? Can you play some music on your phone and sneak it into the duct while you put your ear to the wall from outside?

Comment: Is the duct short and handy enough to use a long pointy thing to dent/make a hole in the siding from inside?

Comment: Siding guys should come back and correct the problem, though I can understand your reluctance to want them back again

Comment: Have you tried tapping on the siding around where you think the hole is? It might sound hollow if you’re lucky.

Comment: Or push a bunch of dry ice into the duct, plug the interior end, and feel for the temperature difference.

Comment: And don't feel bad about the siding guys covering up the exhaust vent.  During a kitchen reno, the drywall guys just pushed up into the attic and closed in the two AC vents in the ceiling.  We were living in the house and so saw what happened and got it corrected immediately (a day or so).